# QUERYING columns from 3 tables using SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, TABLE1, TABLE2 and TABLE3.

TABLE1 have ID and TYPE as columns

TABLE2 have ID, DATE and VALUE as columns

TABLE3 have ID and DESC

Basically TABLE1  is just used as a mapping table. It just tells what type of thing a certain ID is with the TYPE column. We have 1-3 as TYPE.

TABLE2 contains transaction dates per ID. So it's possible to have multiple same ID in TABLE2 but with different DATE. VALUE is just how much the transaction was that DATE for that ID

TABLE3 is like TABLE1 but with a different column DESC.

So my question is how can I query all IDs that are TYPE = 1 (TABLE1) that happened on DATE =  5/27/2018 (TABLE2). The query would contain the columns ID, DATE, VALUE and DESC (TABLE3)

My approach in this one is to use JOIN

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, TABLE2.DATE, TALBE2.VALUE
FROM TALBE2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
WHERE TABLE1.TYPE = 1 AND TABLE2.DATE = '5/27/2018';
```

My problem here is that it doesn't work and it doesn't include TABLE3.DESC yet.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Neither of these use PLSQL, and you have stated Oracle in the Title. I'd removed all your tags, and reference to a RDBMS in the title. Please correct the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are not using the exact SQL statement as given. It has 2 TALBE-TABLE mix ups.

The query should be something like:

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, TABLE2.DATE, TABLE2.VALUE, TABLE3.DESC
FROM TABLE2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.ID
WHERE TABLE1.TYPE = 1 AND TABLE2.DATE = '5/27/2018'
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my sql statement. I was able to get the results i was looking for. Can you elaborate more on what you meant by the TABLE-TABLE mix ups and why you used LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. I wanna understand what happened and not settle for just being spoonfed the correct answers @Sjoerd

Comment: @R.Smith You had typos in your query, wrote TALBE instead of TABLE. The left join takes the full left table (TABLE2) and and matches the ID's from the other tables on the TABLE2. When there are mismatches where TABLE2 has the ID, but the other tables don't, it shows all found data from TABLE2 and no data from the other tables (i.e. those columns will be empty for that ID). When the ID's are there in TABLE1 or TABLE3 but not in TABLE2, they will not show up in the result.